# Conventions for functions that operate on structs

Tags: c, oop, design-patterns

Let's say I have the following in `foo.h`:

```
typedef struct {
    char* my_buf;
    int my_int;
} MyFoo;

/* Creates a foo, allocating memory for my_buf and initializing my_int */
void create_foo(MyFoo *foo);
/* Destroys a foo, freeing the memory for my_buf */
void free_foo(MyFoo *foo);
```

Now in another module, `bar.h` let's say I have the following:

```
#include "foo.h"

/* Do something with a foo */
void do_something(MyFoo *foo, SomeType_t otherType, ...);
```

As written, it's unclear whether or not the `MyFoo` provided to `do_something` should have been initialized with `create_foo`. Since it's not `const`, I think it's reasonably clear that a foo (i.e. space allocated for a foo) should be passed in, it will be modified in some way, and then the user can use the modified foo. But how do I most effectively indicate whether or not that foo should have been 'created'? A common pattern is to do something like

```
MyFoo stackFoo;
do_something(&stackFoo, ...);
```

But then, if `do_something` creates the foo, the user has to know that they're responsible for freeing the foo. On the other hand, there's no way to enforce that the foo should have been created; I'm just asking for a pointer (I admit this is a weak counter argument since it applies to a lot of things in C).

Another option would be to have `MyFoo` include a "created" flag so that it the function can reject any foos that haven't been created, but this seems like I'm over-engineering things.

I just want to be sure I'm not missing a common convention or standard way of handling this. Maybe I'm forcing OOP too much. Thoughts and comments appreciated!

Edit: It was suggested, and I agree, that a better name for `create_foo` would be `init_foo`.

Comment: Documentation. Your create_foo function is misnamed, should be "init_foo", since it doesn't create a foo. Or if it does, it has the wrong signature.

Comment: I figured that's what it would come down to.. (Thanks for the advice on the function naming! I swear naming things is the hardest part of software design)

Comment: @williamg, you should pat yourself on the back for realizing that. A lot of developers don't even after many years of working in the field.

Comment: Changing the post from `create_foo()` to `init_foo()` creates a moving target for SO to answer.  Better to append a comment in the post  than edit the original.

Comment: I don't see where OO comes into play. Perhaps you meant to say "encapsulation". Oh and `free_foo` should be named `destroy_foo`.

Comment: regarding this line: `void init_foo(MyFoo *foo);`,  Is this a pointer to an instance of the struct?  if so, then the returned type should probably be 'int' so the function can return an indication of success/failure of the call to malloc().    However, if this is pointing to an instance of a pointer, (something like: `MyFoo * foo = NULL;`) then the caller should pass the address of 'foo' and the parameter should be `MyFoo **foo` so the caller's variable can be updated.

Comment: It is often effective to use `MyFoo *create_foo(void);` — or pass it value to initialize from.  Then all other functions are expected to pass properly created `MyFoo *` values.  After a value has been passed to `free_foo()`, it should not be used again.  Note that this assumes that `create_foo()` dynamically allocates the structure.  You can enforce this by providing an opaque structure type: `typedef struct MyFoo MyFoo;` in the header, and then defining the structure in the implementation file (`struct MyFoo { … };`) only.  That way, people can only define pointers and not the structures.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The issue I have with that method is it prevents users from allocating `MyFoo`s on the stack. Which I guess isn't the end of the world, and perhaps is a reasonable compromise...

Comment: OK; if that's a problem for you, it isn't the solution to use.  However, you'll find it is actually a very effective way of working, and often beneficial. It looks like your structure is going to allocate memory for the `my_buf` member; it is much better to control access to that by enforcing the discipline of 'use the API functions to manipulate the structure' rather than letting people go behind your back. What happens if someone edits the value in `my_buf` or `my_int` when your code isn't watching?  What happens if I write: `MyFoo f; init_foo(&f); f.my_buf = "consternation"; free_foo(&f);`?

Comment: I like the way libcurl api is constructed and i personally think the convention there is the most intuitive one, check http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html also http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_cleanup.html

Comment: *"have MyFoo include a "created" flag"* can generally be handled within each function itself (presuming your are dynamically allocating the structs). Within each function, let's say you pass `MyFoo *foo` as a parameter, Inside you declare `MyFoo *myfoo = foo ? foo : malloc (sizeof *myfoo);` (or instead of `malloc` call your `init_foo`), which by using a simple *ternary operator* you check wether `foo` is allocated, if not, you allocate for `myfoo`. Operate within the function on `myfoo` and assign (in the case of unallocated `foo`). That can handle the *Is it allocated?* question.

Comment: Everyone has different understandings of what "OOP" means... The thing that separates the correct from the incorrect is whether you can cite from a credible resource (e.g. a very well known programming book) to support your definition. Could it be that the definition you're using might be obscure to everybody but yourself? If the latter is the case, rather than the former, then it might be a good idea to consider the meaning that "OOP" is meant to carry. Keeping in mind that OOP is usually a superset of procedural programming, could it be that this is merely procedural abstraction and not OOP?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are *forcing* OOP, this is no wrong but OOP in C is a matter of orderliness. Whatever, you cannot ensure that a `foo` hasn't been created on stack.

For:

```
void do_something(MyFoo *foo, SomeType_t otherType, ...);
```

it is clear that an existing `foo` is to be passed, as the argument being passed by value. So, the semantic is clear : an existing `foo` must be passed.

For:

```
void create_foo(MyFoo *foo);
```

something's wrong as the argument is passed by value either this should not be called `create_foo` but `init_foo`, or you should pass the argument as an address of a pointer. In case of OOP-like programming you should distinguish allocation and initialization.

```
void init_foo(MyFoo *);

MyFoo foo; // simple creation
init_foo(&foo); // initialization
```

or

```
void init_foo(MyFoo *);
MyFoo *alloc_foo();

MyFoo *pfoo = alloc_foo(); // allocation factory
init_foo(pfoo); // initialization
// or with an idiom like
MyFoo *pfoo;
init_foo(pfoo=alloc_foo());
```

or:

```
MyFoo *init_foo(MyFoo *);
MyFoo *alloc_foo();

MyFoo *pfoo = init_foo(alloc_foo());
```

Now you can also make a single call to a convenient function:

```
MyFoo *create_foo(); // alloc+initialization factory
MyFoo *pfoo = create_foo();
```

or with a *pass-a-pointer* idiom:

```
void create_foo(MyFoo **f);
MyFoo *pfoo;
create_foo(&pfoo);
```

If you want you can use an opaque type using modularity, to have a better control of your allocations, but at the end it will not ensure that user is not cheating:

```
// Module foo.c
struct internal_foo {
  int m;
};
void *create_foo() {
  struct internal_foo *pfoo = malloc(...);
  // init structure
  return pfoo;
}
void delete_foo(void *pf) {
  free(pf);
}
// convenient functions for members
void set_m_foo(void *pf,int v) { ((struct internal_foo *)pf)->m = v; }
int get_m_foo(void *pf) { return ((struct internal_foo *)pf)->m; }
```

thus from an external point, user can only see a generic pointer. If you want to ensure a much better typing, then you can also encapsulate the generic pointer into a dummy structure: `struct MyFoo { void *opaque_foo; }`.